# How do I detect certain block types anywhere in a certain area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command block that detects water blocks anywhere in my world, and then replace it with ice, but I don't know how to detect blocks without testing specific coordinates one by one. For example, this won't work because I have to repeat for every single coordinate I want to test:

```
/execute if block 12 23 34 water run setblock 12 23 34 ice
```

I also want it to detect blocks everywhere without being restricted by distance from the player or other entities.

Comment: Welcome to Stack exchange! Take some time to read the Tour, and make sure your questions are good. I left an upvote, so now you have a little more rep.

Answer (score 2):

The command syntax is

```
/fill <from> <to> <block> replace [<filter>]
```

So in your case it is something like

```
/fill ~-25 ~-10 ~-25 ~25 ~10 ~25 minecraft:ice replace minecraft:water
```

which would be execute off of the player every few seconds to get it all. This wouldn't get it all at once but wherever the player moves.

---

Note this may work slower if a lot of people are in the same world.

Comment: So THAT was the command! Spent forever trying to find one that worked, but ya beat me to it. Good job!